# If I've signed the Canonical Contributors agreement, do I have to sign the new Harmony Agreement?

Tags: community, canonical, license, contributing

The contributors agreement has changed to a broad license harmony agreement. Do I need to resign the new agreement or is it automatic. Does anything prevent me from signing the new agreement and using that as a basis for my contributions and Should I sign the new agreement, is it legally safer?

- Note, I have personally never signed the old Canonical agreement, this question is from other members of the community.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the [www.canonical.com/contributors/faq](http://www.canonical.com/contributors/faq) FAQ:

> 

- **If I signed the old agreement, do I need to sign the new one too?**

  No, if you previously accepted the Canonical Contributor Agreement 2.5 (or earlier), your future contributions will continue to be covered by that. However, if you wish, you can sign the new Contributor License Agreement, in which case the terms of the new agreement will cover any new contributions.